# Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\x80qA\x0Eg\x04...' for column 'email' at row 1:' while trying to delete a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete a row on my "usuarios" table in MySQL (Which has 2 VARBINARY columns, "email" and "password" to store encrypted values (With DES_DECRYPT() ).

I can insert without problems, but if I try to delete anything it gives me this error:

**Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\x80qA\x0Eg\x04...' for column 'email' at row 1:'**

I'm trying to delete it with a Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `borrar_empleado`(IN idParamint(11))
BEGIN
    delete from usuario where idUsuario = idParam;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And with a simple

```
DELETE FROM usuario WHERE idUsuario=*number*;
```

And the same error happens.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info e.g. a show create table usuario ?

Comment: Here you go:

`create table Usuario ( idUsuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL, ApPaterno varchar(50) NOT NULL, ApMaterno varchar(50) NOT NULL, email varbinary(50) NOT NULL, contrasena varbinary(50) NOT NULL );`

Because of time, I got a work around on it by adding a column named "active" which tells me if the user is currently working if '1' or not if '0'. But if I could find a reason for the other error I would be very thankfull.

Comment: Typically that 1366 error has to do with invalid encoded data. Why you get it on a binary field while deleting is so far a mystery to me.

Maybe to help others along what encoding is the database in and what encoding is your connection in ?